# Am I getting this invitation early?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, jobs, email

I'm a little confused about these "invitations" to Stack Overflow Careers. I haven't reached 200 reputation on any community yet, but the email says that:

> Getting 200 reputation is no easy feat. Consider this a rite of passage...

Am I being sent this invitation early?

Comment: Is this a mail, an ad on the site... or else?

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau It's an email sent from do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: This should clearly not happen, will look into it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR:** There was a mistake in the invitation email copy, which is now fixed.

The email mentioned 200 reputation while the actual criterion for getting invited is to have at least one answer on Stack Overflow that is more than 7 days old and has a score >= 1. Users who satisfy this threshold get an invite automatically.

Sorry for the confusion, and thanks for your report!